# Understanding Server-Side JavaScript via WSProxy with the SOAP API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap, ssjs

I recently stumbled across the WSProxy which seems to be interesting particularly as they seem to be more convenient to use than traditional soap calls and reduce performance overhead.

[WsProxy Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_useSSJS.htm)

I am trying it out, but can seem to get it to work.

I am running the sample code as a script activity in Automation Studio and here is my code:

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("core","1");
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();

var guid = Platform.Function.GUID();
var name = "my test de - " + guid;

var de = {
    Name: name,
    CustomerKey: guid,
    Description: "Another DE added via SSJS",
    Fields: [{
        FieldType: "Text",
        Name: "ID",
        MaxLength: 36,
        IsPrimaryKey: true,
        IsNillable: false,
        IsRequired: true
    },
    {
        FieldType: "Text",
        Name: "Name",
        MaxLength: 200
    }],
    CategoryID: 101377
}

var res = prox.createItem("DataExtension", de);
</script>
```

The script runs, but the  DE is not created. 
I would appreciate any pointers on this.

Comment: The code is works for me within really small change - CategoryId, so check your CategoryId

Comment: When is change it the activity fails :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CategoryID you are using is taken from [Official Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_create.htm) so you need to replace it with yours.

Just hover with mouse on your Data Extension folder and check status bar:
[image]

you will find categoryId there.